# Debold discord.py emebed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm making an embed on my discord bot and I'm wanting to remove the big line between the numbers I've tried `name='** **'` and `name='ub200b'` but no matter what it will show the annoying blank line

[image]

Code:

```
embed5 = discord.Embed(
        title = response,
        description = 'Once you give me 5 names I will make op.gg Multisearch',
        colour = discord.Colour.red()
    )
  
  
    embed5.set_footer(text='footer')
    embed5.add_field(name='_Names_', value=f'`{opgg1.content}`', inline=False)
    embed5.add_field(name='\u200b', value=f'`{opgg2.content}`', inline=False)
    embed5.add_field(name='\u200b', value=f'`{opgg3.content}`', inline=False)
    embed5.add_field(name='\u200b', value=f'`{opgg4.content}`', inline=False)
    embed5.add_field(name='\u200b', value=f'`{opgg5.content}`', inline=False)
  
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, and that's the answer. The solution is to do it inside the description instead of using fields

```py
embed5 = discord.Embed(
        title = response,
        description = f'Once you give me 5 names I will make op.gg Multisearch\n**_Names_**\n`{opgg1.content}`\n`{opgg2.content}`\n`{opgg3.content}`\n`{opgg4.content}`\n`{opgg5.content}`',
        colour = discord.Colour.red()
    )
```

[image]

`\n` is a `newline` character.

You can also leave two lines, here is how that will look:

```py
embed5 = discord.Embed(
        title = "Send me the summoner names",
        description = f'Once you give me 5 names I will make op.gg Multisearch\n**_Names_**\n`{opgg1.content}`\n\n`{opgg12.content}`\n\n`{opgg3.content}`\n\n`{opgg4.content}`\n\n`{opgg5.content}`',
        colour = discord.Colour.red()
    )
```

[image]